# Vite preview not working properly in a Vite React App

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

Created a React App using Vite, then ran `npm run build` and `npm run preview`, but it's not working. I get a totally blank page and an error that says:

`TypeError: e is null` and `Uncaught TypeError: e is null`

[image: Errors Screenshot]

My `vite.config.js` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
});
```

My `package.json` file (if that matters):

```json
{
  "name": "homepage",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Got it solved! The react components in my project had some errors that didn't show up in the webpage created by `npm run dev` but they were the ones which caused the error. Some of them were component file name not being same as the component function name (the one which gets `export default function`ed) and importing the same file under two names. All-in-all some of the components had errors that didn't show in the dev window and did in the build. Check your components for errors people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `@types` installed. Are you using a global `typescript`? That's not installed.

Also, what does your **tsconfig.node.json** look like? A valid one is:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Make sure your **tsconfig.json** links to the node tsconfig:

```js
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
```

The rest of the code you showed looks fine. I hope that helps!

**EDIT**** Also take a look at this working example fairly similar to yours, it may help you track the issue down. There's a successfuil `build` and `preview` in this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-sammet-imfzl5

Comment: I neither have nor used typescript. While creating the project, I'd selected Javascript as the language for the project. Extremely grateful for taking out time to answer this question, only thing I wanna know now is what do I do to fix it? should I remove @types from the package.json? Or get TS installed on the system? Again, thank you very much

Comment: I would try removing node_modules and your .lock file then install again. Either `yarn install` or `npm install`. Those type definitions can be removed but they are not the cause of the issue.

Do you see any errors in `main.jsx` or `App.jsx` when running development? It seems likely there's some reference to something `null` as the error mentions.

Here's a sandbox that uses your package.json - using a new Vite.js project initially: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/determined-wood-3n8cfs

It works fine - so I suspect an issue in one of your app's components.